# Cleaner syntax for If object present put object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a cleaner syntax for the below example? Obviously it's not too much of an issue for the example, but with method calls and arrays as part of the object, I ideally want a super local variable for just this object, i.e. 'this' or something.

`obj? obj : ''`

if object is present, put object. Otherwise put nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual Ruby-ish way to do this is with a short-circuiting OR:

```
obj || ''
```

Remember that this doesn't work properly if `obj` could legitimately be `false`; you're better off testing against `obj.nil?` explicitly in that case.

If you have big chains of methods that you need to send and any of the results could be `nil`, have a look at the [andand gem](http://andand.rubyforge.org/):

```
obj.andand.somemethod.andand.anothermethod || ''
```

Finally, if you're using Rails, ActiveSupport gives you the [`try` method](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/Object/try):

```
obj.try(:somemethod).try(:anothermethod) || ''
```

Comment: Awesome. Is there an easy way to return `nil`, even if you're checking a sub-object? ie, I have a hash and I want to write `obj['attr'] || ''`, however if my `obj` is nil, then it crashes rather than returning the `or` statement.

Comment: That's what the andand gem does -- it would let you write `obj.andand['attr'] || ''`, for example.

Comment: Cool. I'll check it out!

Comment: There's also `.try` which is already in Rails. Also note that `nil.to_s == ''` so if `obj` is a string then you could just `obj.to_s` to hide the conditional.

Comment: @muistooshort Oh! Right. I always forget about that.